# What Goes in the Controller for an AJAX get request in GRAILS

Tags: ajax, grails, controller

I have an AJAX call in my view,

```
var ajaxData= $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "${createLink(controller:'profile',action:'ajaxList')}",
success: function(data) {
    }  
});
```

I created a method in the ProfileController.groovy class in order to return "data" from this call, but I don' know how to format the controller correctly. Here is what I want to return. The model, profile, has a name and a description. I want to return a hash object where the key is the name and the value is the description. Is there a way to do this in the controller so that this ajax call returns that hash. Any help would be aprpeciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller's `ajaxList` action build your model as you want it, as usual, and then instead of `return model` at the end you want to `render model as JSON`.

For example,

```
class ProfileController {
    def ajaxList() {
        def profiles = Profile.list()
        def model = profiles.collect { [(it.name): it.description] }
        render model as JSON
    }
}
```

And if you want to use the same `list` action for returning different formats, look at using [`withFormat`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html).

Comment: I have never really done custom controllers, i've just used generations. Do you think you can give a little code example of how that would look for this case?

Comment: thanks for the update, that makes sense. However, where does the data come from then. AKA there is no query to the database to get profiles in this case?

Comment: I updated the example to guess at your domain class and requirements.

Comment: so my code from above should now set ajaxdata= a map of the name description pair?